# Copy video to application tmp folder from extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova

I have an app along with an app extension, written in SWIFT. Within the extension, I allow a user to select a video file from the camera roll, and I subsequently open the app to do further processing on the video file.

```
private func loadUTIDictionnary(content: NSExtensionItem,f: Dictionary<String,String> -> Void) {
    var dict = Dictionary<String, String>()

    loadUTIString(content, utiKey: contentTypeMovie, handler: { movie_NSSecureCoding in
        let movie_NSurl = movie_NSSecureCoding as! NSURL
        let movie_String = movie_NSurl.absoluteString as String

        dict["movie"] = movie_String
        f(dict)
    })
}
```

In the above code snippet, `movie_String` is the absolute path to the clip:

```
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1349.MOV
```

My app itself is a Cordova application, however. Within Cordova, you only have access to the private app sandbox.

```
/var/mobile/Applications/UUID
```

Is there a way to copy the movie file to the app sandbox from within the extension?